# how to sum object array with same key value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array of object like this :

```
var original_db = [
            {date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
{date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
        ];
```

and here is my expected result:

```
result : 
[
{date_diff : "2016/10/31", NORMAL_CLEARING : 2, NO_ANSWER : 1, ORIGINATOR-CANCEL : 1},
{date_diff : "2016/10/30", NORMAL_CLEARING : 1, NO_ANSWER : 3},
{date_diff : "2016/10/29", NORMAL_CLEARING : 1, ORIGINATOR-CANCEL : 2}
]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i try this code.....var dict = {}; for (i = 0; i < original_db.length; i++) {var value = original_db[i]["hangup_cause"]; var count = (dict[value] || 0) + 1; dict[value] = count;}...but the result is not what i want.

Comment: Please review [ask], and update your question to include a [mcve] of ***what you've tried***, otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of a `for` loop, check if the "date_number" is the same as on the previous iteration.

If it's not the same date, `push()` the object in an array and reset it.

This code snippet is working.

```js
var original_db = [
    {date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/31", date_number:1,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/30", date_number:2,hangup_cause:"NO_ANSWER"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"NORMAL_CLEARING"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
    {date_diff:"2016/10/29", date_number:3,hangup_cause:"ORIGINATOR-CANCEL"},
];
  
var resultArr = [];
var resultObj = {};
var date_number = 1;

for (i=0; i<original_db.length; i++) {
    
    // If the "date_number" changed, push the object to array.
    if (date_number != original_db[i]["date_number"]){
        date_number = original_db[i]["date_number"]
        resultArr.push(resultObj);
        resultObj = {};
    }
    
    // Count add each "hangup_cause" and its count
    resultObj["date_diff"] = original_db[i]["date_diff"];
    var value = original_db[i]["hangup_cause"]; 
    var count = (resultObj[value] || 0) + 1; 
    resultObj[value] = count;
}

// Push the last object at the end of the loop
resultArr.push(resultObj);

// Show it in console.
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArr))
```